# How to make a switch statement run over and over without getting stuck on load?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

The switch statement work fine when it is in the floor() function, but then it doesn't run whenever the variable is changed outside the function, so i want the switch statement to run all the time. Tried using a while loop, but then the page is stuck on load. Tried to put the switch statement outside the function, but then the switch statement doesn't get triggered? That's what i assume at least, cause nothing happens.

```
var level = 0;

function floor() {
  level += 1;
  switch (level) {
    case 1:
      if (level = 1) {
        document.getElementById("floor1").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (level = 2) {
        document.getElementById("floor2").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if (level = 3) {
        document.getElementById("floor3").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if (level = 4) {
        document.getElementById("floor4").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if (level = 5) {
        document.getElementById("floor5").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
    case 6:
      if (level = 6) {
        document.getElementById("floor6").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 7:
      if (level = 7) {
        document.getElementById("floor7").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 8:
      if (level = 8) {
        document.getElementById("floor8").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 9:
      if (level = 9) {
        document.getElementById("floor9").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 10:
      if (level = 10) {
        document.getElementById("floor10").style.backgroundColor = "black"
      }
    default:

  }
}

function game1true() {
  level += 1;
}
function game1false() {
  life -= 1;
}
```

Comment: You are assigning values to `level` with a single equals sign. [You want `level === 1` etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: Also PLEASE DRY `document.getElementById("floor"+level).style.backgroundColor = "black";`

Comment: you should start another thread to let this loop run without affecting the UI. But I think that it's not possible in javascript/web.

Comment: @mplungjan but i want the earlier levels to be black/market aswell not just the one the user is currently on

Comment: You have not posted enough code to figure out what you want, I do not see a call to floor() anywhere. But I can only guess you repeat yourself endlessly with names like game1true - assuming you have game2true too... Just add `document.getElementById("floor"+level).style.backgroundColor = "black";` to whereever you are calling floor now. If you need to loop, do `for (var i=1;i<=numberOfLevels; i++) document.getElementById("floor"+i).style.backgroundColor = "black";`

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are assigning values in every case to `level` with the single equals sign. [Comparisons make use of `==` and `===`operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). For example:

```
case 1:
  if (level === 1) {
    document.getElementById("floor1").style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
```

However, there is no need for the switch statement here as you're assigning black in all cases. Simply use `level` in the selector.

```
function floor() {
  level += 1;
  document.getElementById(`floor${level}`).style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

• [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set level var inside your floor function ? It is like pass through a state machine:

```js
var level = 0;

function floor(newLevel) {
  level = newLevel;
  switch (level) {
    case 1:
      if (level = 1) {
        document.getElementById("floor1").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (level = 2) {
        document.getElementById("floor2").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if (level = 3) {
        document.getElementById("floor3").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if (level = 4) {
        document.getElementById("floor4").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if (level = 5) {
        document.getElementById("floor5").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
    case 6:
      if (level = 6) {
        document.getElementById("floor6").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 7:
      if (level = 7) {
        document.getElementById("floor7").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 8:
      if (level = 8) {
        document.getElementById("floor8").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 9:
      if (level = 9) {
        document.getElementById("floor9").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 10:
      if (level = 10) {
        document.getElementById("floor10").style.backgroundColor = "black"
      }
    default:

  }
}

function game1true() {
  floor(level + 1);
}
function game1false() {
  life -= 1;
}
```